# .htaccess on real site not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think my `.htaccess` is not working. Just want to ask about .routing in fuelphp. Currently, I'm uploading my website into the real server. When I upload it. Home page is only okay (mydomain.com), the rest of the pages are not working (mydomain.com/page1). I try to change the .htaccess and remove the comment of AllowOverride All and RewriteBase / but still not working.

This is the directory of my website in the server.

```
server directory
  var/
    www/
      html/
        fuel/
        public/
        (other files)
```

And this is my htaccess. Check it here. http://bin.fuelphp.com/snippet/view/LH

Comment: Add the htaccess in question. Do not link to external websites.

Comment: This is most likely a web server configuration issue: do you have rewrite module enabled? Do you have .htaccess enabled in your virtualhost?

Comment: what do you mean, when you write "htaccess not work" ? Are you get 404 error? or something else?